# Can Authentication Filter be used if I dont want a challenge and response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am going to use HMAC to secure a web api. On each request to an api controller, I want to check to see if the request is valid based on some pre-defined criteria.

Im looking at building a custom authorization filter, but one of the methods of the IAuthenticationFilter interface adds an auth challenge/response.  I dont want to do this, so how can I just ignore that part? Or, is there a better type of attribute to implement (eg. action attribute)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can implement AuthorizeAttribute derived from System.web.Http.
In this you can override OnAuthorization method to perform your custom authorization. Have a look at an example below.

```
     public class ApiAuthorizationFilterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {


    /// <summary>
    /// Performs custom authorization based on incoming request  
    ///  value(header)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        //Checking for any controller decorated with AllowAnonymousAttribute
        bool skipAuthorization = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
        if (skipAuthorization) {
            return;
        }

        if (!IsAuthorized(actionContext)) {

            actionContext.Response = ApiHttpResponseMessage.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext.Request);
            return;
        }
        if (!IsUserAuthorized(actionContext)) {
            actionContext.Response = ApiHttpResponseMessage.CreateResponse(actionContext.Request, ErrorMessages.INVALID_CMF_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, that helps.  I found this article helpful as well  http://www.infoworld.com/article/2988903/application-architecture/how-to-secure-web-api-using-authorization-filters.html